# how to remove listitem during fragment swipes in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created the two nested fragment tabs.A  listitem duplicates is added during page selected between the two fragment tabs.The duplicates are added only at time of swiping the fragments fastly.if i selected the page smoothly means listview does not created duplicates.What is the solution to remove the duplicates of listview in android?`

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_explore_next, container, false);

        FontChangeCrawler fontChanger = new FontChangeCrawler(getContext().getAssets(), "arial.ttf");
        fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup) rootview);

        final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        hashSet.addAll(movieList);
        movieList.clear();
        movieList.addAll(hashSet);

        peoplelist = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.peoplelist);
        taglist = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.taglist);
        usermsg = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.usernotfound);
        search = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.searchbar);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter2(getActivity(), movieList);
        peoplelist.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        peoplelist.setAdapter(null);
        peoplelist.setAdapter(adapter);
        peoplelist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adapter1 = new CustomListAdapter21(getActivity(), movieList1);
        taglist.setItemsCanFocus(false);

        taglist.setAdapter(adapter1);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootview.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2-1);//Caching Fragment view

        PageListener pageListener = new PageListener();
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);

        search = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.searchbar);

        peoplelist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                // ListView Clicked item index
                System.out.println("item clicked");
            }
        });

        movieList.clear();

        getPeople();
//        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }





    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new PeopleFragment(), "PEOPLE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TagFragment(), "TAGS");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.requestTransparentRegion(viewPager);
    }

    public class PageListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            System.out.println("position in view pager" + position);
            movieList.clear();

            if (position == 0) {
                text = "people";
                search.setHint("Search people");
                usermsg.setText("No Username found");
                search.setText("");
                movieList.clear();
                getPeople();

            } else {
                text = "tag";
                search.setHint("Search hashtags");
                search.setText("");
                usermsg.setText("# No Hash tag found");
                movieList1.clear();
                getHashTag();

            }

        }
    }



    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        //mContainer.removeAllViews();
        ViewGroup mContainer = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editprofilenext);
        mContainer.removeAllViews();

        mContainer.clearFocus();
        mContainer.removeAllViewsInLayout();

        ((View) movieList).clearFocus();


        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
```

CustomListAdapter2`

```
class CustomListAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
        private Activity activity;
        private Context mContext;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<Movie> movieItems;
        private List<FeedItem> feedlist;
        private List<Movie> mStringFilterList;
        ValueFilter valueFilter;
        public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

        ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        public CustomListAdapter2(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.movieItems = movieItems;
            this.mStringFilterList = movieItems;
            this.mStringFilterList.addAll(movieItems);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return movieItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return movieItems.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder mHolder;
            final Movie m = movieItems.get(position);
            final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (imageLoader == null)
                imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                mHolder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_people, null);
                FontChangeCrawler fontChanger = new FontChangeCrawler(getContext().getAssets(), "arial.ttf");
                fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup) convertView);
                mHolder.thumbNail = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.image5);
                mHolder.Username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
                mHolder.Fullname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
                convertView.setTag(mHolder);
            }
            else
            {
                mHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            mHolder.Username.setText(m.getUsername());
            mHolder.Fullname.setText(m.getFullname());
            Glide.with(convertView.getContext()).load(m.getThumbnailUrl()).asBitmap().override(100, 100).placeholder(R.drawable.profileicon).centerCrop().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(mHolder.thumbNail) {
                @Override
                protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                    RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                            RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(view.getContext().getResources(), resource);
                    circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                    mHolder.thumbNail.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                }
            });


            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    getChildFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.editprofilenext, ParallaxProfileActivity.newInstance(m.getid()), ParallaxProfileActivity.TAG)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            });


            return convertView;
        }
        private class ViewHolder {
            private TextView Username, Fullname;
            private ImageView thumbNail;


        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            if (valueFilter == null) {
                valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
            }
            return valueFilter;
        }


        private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                    List<Movie> filterList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                        if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getUsername().toUpperCase())
                                .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                            Movie country = new Movie();
                            Movie m = mStringFilterList.get(i);

                            filterList.add(m);
                        }
                    }
                    results.count = filterList.size();
                    results.values = filterList;
                } else {
                    results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                    results.values = mStringFilterList;
                }
                return results;

            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                movieItems = (List<Movie>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        }
    }
```

`

Comment: please post your CustomListAdapter2 class ... i think problem is there

Comment: Now i have posted the adapter @tanim reja

Comment: for little bit clarification : You have a Activity and it has two fragment A,B. A and B both contains listview (with same item) and during fragment swipe  from A to B , in B's listview a duplication has occurred.  am i right ?

Comment: No in both listview the duplicates occured only at the time of swiping fastly

Comment: Both fragment have separate list item

Answer (score 0):

try this in your pagelistener class . clear both list and call notifyDataSetChanged(),

```
if (position == 0) {
            text = "people";
            search.setHint("Search people");
            usermsg.setText("No Username found");
            search.setText("");
            movieList.clear();
            movieList1.clear();                
            getPeople();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } else {
            text = "tag";
            search.setHint("Search hashtags");
            search.setText("");
            usermsg.setText("# No Hash tag found");
            movieList.clear();
            movieList1.clear();
            getHashTag();
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

if it does not work then let me know i will try another solution..

Comment: Any one give alternate solution for this issue